# update apk programmatically (without root)

Tags: android

I want to update my android application programmatically.

I used following code:

```
 final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new 
       File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/AndroidTest.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

This code display dialogue box to install application.

I want to install apk automatically.

Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious security reasons. Apps cannot install apps without user intervention, with the exception of certain system apps that have the right permissions and such.

Comment: @HemantVc: The Play Store is a system app that has the right permissions and such.

Answer (score 0):

Yes **It is possible** Please check this [out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40736710/4741746) 
For this you need SUPER_USERACCESS 
Add this permission: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />`