# Android update app programmatically

Tags: android

I have an app, but I want to update it, I read some post of "stackoverflow" (update application programmatically)

> [Android programmatically update application when a new version is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709443/android-programmatically-update-application-when-a-new-version-is-available)
>
> [update apk programmatically (without root)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712590/update-apk-programmatically-without-root)

but none convince me.

I would like information on how to update an app.

Right now my app is not uploaded on google play, I have it in apk.

> I would upgrade using a button [update click here], and that she is
>   going to take charge "http:www.site/myapk.apk" and to update.

Why say the apk? because every week I will update my app a bit.

And if they have to always download the apk, it is very frustrating.

There an easy and clean way (with code)?

Comment: I have not found anything. any example full ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57250843/4694013

Comment: you can check this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213211/update-an-android-app-without-google-play/68272237#68272237

Answer (score 12):

please visit this link you may get some idea [LINK](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/05/android-update-application.html)

It follows these steps ::

> 1 Create a Web Service which your app can poll whenever the app
>   launches or based on some time limit that can check if there is new
>   version out there.
>
> 2. This Web service should return the lastest Version of the apk file that is hosted on the Server along with the URI of the application
>      file that has the new version.
> 3. When your app gets the response from the Web Service, it will parse the JSON and check your app version to the lastest version that is
>      available on the server.
> 4. If your app version is lower than the latest version it will prompt the user to start the download process. The download of the new app is
>      handled by the Download Manager.
> 5. The download manager will notify your app using Broadcast receiver when the download is complete.
> 6. After completion of the latest version of the application file the you can start the activity to install/update that file.

Answer (score 5):

Try this option

Add google library to update from the application

```
  dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.5.0'
...}
```

refer doc from below link

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates#update_readiness