# How change version code and version name programatically?

Tags: android

I want to update my app changing the value of the version and name, I do not find nothing, about change version programatically

Comment: Simply said, **you can't**. But you can use some FAKE strings to show to the user.

Comment: You want to change the version name text dynamically from Androidmenifest to your activity ? or you want reverse ?

Comment: I need update my App, and I need compare with versión of web, from my pone, and update my phone

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it.

```
version = sys.argv[1]
gradle_file = './path/to/your/build.gradle'
with open(gradle_file, 'r+') as file:
    offset = 0
    previous_line_length = 0
    for line in file:
        if "versionName" in line:
            previous_line_length = len(line)
            break
        offset += len(line)

    new_line = '        versionName "'+version+'"'
    # add spaces at the end if new line is shorter than previous
    diff = previous_line_length - len(new_line) - 1 # minus 1 for the carriage return char
    length_diff = diff if diff >= 0 else 0
    for i in range(length_diff):
        new_line += ' '
    new_line += '\n'
    file.seek(offset)
    file.write(new_line)
```

This is a python script, you call it with the new version string, for example:

python script.py 1.2.3

You will need to add safety spaces at the end of the versionName line in your build.gradle file, otherwise a longer version name will mess up the file.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

For Android you can easily increase versionCode and versionName by

add this to your gradle script and also create a file version.properties with VERSION_CODE=555

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion 30
        buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    
        def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
        if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
            def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
    
            versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
    
            def code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger() + 1
    
            versionProps['VERSION_CODE'] = code.toString()
            versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)
    
    
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "app.umanusorn.playground"
                minSdkVersion 29
                targetSdkVersion 30
                versionCode code
                versionName code.toString()
```

Answer (score -1):

Version Name & Version code you must mention in Manifest Itself , so you can change and give Update manually but You can't change programaticallly

Comment: and how I can update my App ?  / check ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393950/android-update-app-programmatically

Comment: If you want manual update follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213211/update-an-android-app-without-google-play

Comment: You can, just not in the android app.  You can do it via a script that changes your manifest/other file with a version number in it.  Most companies eventually add this to their build system.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it rather doing in manifest.xml