# Update android app on multiple devices automatically

Tags: android, auto-update

We have built a kiosk mode application on Android which is running on over 100 tablets. The app on each tab has been downloaded from the playstore. We want the tabs to be updated as soon as a new version has been uploaded on the playstore. However, we notice that the playstore account gets logged out on most of the tabs. I would like to know if there is any limit on the number of tabs a single account can be used on? Also, is there a better way of uploading and updating our app on all our devices. **All devices are logged in with the same google ID.** We are planning to have over 1000 devices soon. What would be the best method to upload a new version of our app and keep all our apps updated on all tabs? Is there a better method outside the playstore? Also, note that there is no one to manually download/update/install the app on the devices. It must happen automatically. Thanks.

Comment: Found a similar solution here. Please check, [Android Update app programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393950/android-update-app-programmatically)

Comment: turn on Auto update in your google play account. Then your app will get updated on tabs as soon as you upload to play store.

Comment: @ClintPaul The solution requires the user to click on OK to start the download. Whereas I am looking at auto download and install like how it happens with playstore updates.

Comment: @Sunny Playstore isnt working for us as it logs out from the devices when we login to another device. I suspect there is a limit on the number of devices that we can login with using a single ID.