# How to update application in background like Facebook, Instagram , Messenger is doing?

Tags: android, facebook, instagram, app-update, in-app-update

I want to know exactly what Facebook, Instagram, Messenger is doing for background Application update (App-Update)? 
I observed they are updating applications outside playstore is it without user intervention?

Comment: You should use Service/WorkManager/AlarmManager or something like that to update your application in background

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman , Shahnawaz is asking about app update not updating UI from background.

Comment: Is that possible at all? Hope this help you:  https://www.facebook.com/help/456186367793974

Comment: No @Md.Asaduzzaman the link is all about turn on/off background app update, I want app update like Facebook did.

Comment: Actually Facebook use background service to do that through it's `App Manager`. You have to provide something like that to achieve this. Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393950/android-update-app-programmatically

Comment: you can't update a native Android app without user interaction. If it is a hybrid/progressive web app, then you just download new HTML/JS code from your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Facebook, Instagram, Messenger are all hybrid apps so the code base consists of HTML, javascript and any accompanying images which are bundled together and distributed as part of a platform-specific binary(.apk /.ipa). Once published you can't change the native code(Java/Kotlin/Swift/Objective C) but you can change your CSS, javascript, and images by using [Code push](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/) plugin and For react native you can use [React native module](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push) of code push.